# Array of Char in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, input, char

I'm trying to create a function that get a string, taking char by char:

```
char * GetString (int dim) // dim is the size of the string
{
    char c, *S;
    int i = 0;

    S = (char*)malloc(dim*(sizeof(char));

    while ((c=getchar() != '\n') && (i < dim) && (c != EOF))
    {
        S[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    S[i] = '/0';

    return S;
}
```

The problem is when i try to use a "printf" in this function, trying to see if the input was taken correctly, it shows me strange characters, not the ones i inserted. I don't know what i'm missing.

Thanks very much.

Comment: [**DO NOT** cast the return value of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: `c` should be an `int` and don't cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: I edited but nothings happen.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, so multiplying by it is pointless.

Comment: Do you compile on a 64bit system **and** miss to `#include` `stdlib.h`?

Comment: I'm on 64 but i inserted it.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Are you getting any warnings?

Comment: CodeBlocks with GCC, no got 0 warnings. I think the problem is when i do: 
S[i] = c, because if i print the value of c = getchar() che char is taken correctly, but if i do S[i] = c or *(S) = c and try to print S, it shows me strange characters.

Answer (score 6):

This should be a backslash:

```
S[i] = '\0';
```

Make sure your compiler warnings are turned on and you're paying attention to them. `'/0'` is a non-standard multi-character integer literal.

Backslash zero '\0' is the C string NUL-terminator you're after.

Also, in the case where your input is larger than `dim`, you are overrunning your buffer, writing one byte more than you allocated. I would suggest allocating `dim+1` bytes.

Finally, there's no point in multiplying by `sizeof(char)` - it is 1 by definition.

P.S. Now is an excellent time to learn how to use a debugger. If you're using GNU tools: `gcc -Wall -Werror main.c` then `gdb a.out`, and type r to run.

Comment: also he's not allocating space for that character.

Comment: Thanks very much, i edited but nothing, same output.

Comment: For completeness: `S[i] = 0;` would do also.

Answer (score 3):

This `'/0'` is a character constant which value is implementation defined. So you have to replace it with escape character `'\0'`.

Also you have to allocate `dim + 1` bytes if you want to append exactly dim characters with the terminating zero.

The function can look like

```
char * GetString( int dim )
{
    char *s;
    int i;

    s = ( char* )malloc( ( dim + 1 ) *( sizeof( char ) );

    i = 0;
    while ( i < dim && ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n') && ( c != EOF ) )
    {
        s[i++] = c;
    }

    s[i] = '\0';

    return s;
}
```

Comment: I tryed with your code but nothing, the results is the same.. for example, i insert "aaa" and it prints three shi**y smiley !

Comment: @Mauri I do not see what code you are running. The code snippet I showed is vlaid.

Comment: "*vlaid*" nice typo! ;-)

Comment: I'm using your snippet but got the same problem.

Comment: @ Mauri See my updated post and try the function one more by copy and paste it. There was a typo.

Comment: IT WORKS, what changes?

Comment: THE fu***** parenthesis in c != getchar()... Thanks very much mate.

Comment: @Mauri , Please stop using bad language!! That attitude might get you suspended or banned.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **Vlads from Moscow** for the right snippets. The problem was here:

```
while (c = getchar() != '\n')
```

It's wrong, the right way:

```
while ((c=getchar()) != '\n')
```

Comment: If Vlad's answer was useful to you, vote it up. You may want to comment on the answer itself.

Comment: I did it,  i couldn't first because i had a low level.

Comment: Not enough rep to comment is not an excuse to post a comment as an answer.

Comment: Man are you serious? i've found the right way, haven't i to tell others? bah.. you think more for a reputation of a true problem solved.. good logic man

Answer (score 1):

The code had an amazingly simple problem: you missed parentheses around `c=getchar()`. Try `((c=getchar()) != '\n')` instead of `(c=getchar() != '\n')`
The code has other problems also, like using `/0` instead of `\0`

Here is the rectified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * GetString (int dim) // dim is the size of the string
{
    char c, *S;
    int i = 0;

    S = (char*)malloc(dim*(sizeof(char)));

    while (((c=getchar()) != '\n') && (i < dim) && (c != EOF))
    {
        S[i] = c;
        i++;
    }

    S[i] = '\0';

    return S;
}

int main()
{
    char *s;

    s = GetString(10);
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);

    return 0;
}
```